# Why can't I cut a video clip using OpenShot?

Tags: video-editing

I'm trying to adjust the start time and end time of a clip in OpenShot. According to [the manual](https://cdn.openshot.org/static/files/user-guide/clips.html#cutting-slicing):

> OpenShot has many easy ways to adjust the start and end positions of a
> clip (otherwise known as cutting). The most common method is simply
> grabbing the left (or right) edge of the clip and dragging.

However, no matter where I position my mouse cursor over a clip, dragging it will just drag the
whole clip to a new location, instead of adjusting the start/end time. There is no handle at the edges at al.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of a clip in the timeline of OpenShot]

Comment: which version of OpenShot?

Comment: Whichever one was the latest version 7 months ago ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯